# JSP for setting the BASE HTML Tag

Tags: jsp, base-tag

I am running an application using jsp (gsp actually) under Tomcat.
All URLs are absolute. That is, every href begins with a "/".
For example:

```
<a href="/mytool/role/index" class="menulink">Role</a>
```

Every request will receive a parameter called SYS.WEBSYSTEM_PREFIX which 
must be prepended to every URL.

That is, if the request is

```
http://myDomain/mytool/xxx?SYS.WEBSYSTEM_PREFIX=some_path
```

then the URL from above has to be rewritten as:

```
    some_path/mytool/index
```

I think that this can be globally done using the HTML  tag.

I've intended the following:

```
<base href=<% request.getParameter("SYS.WEBSYSTEM_PREFIX"); %> />
```

but it didn't work.

Therefore the questions are:

- Is possible to cope this problem in this way?
- If yes. How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Luis

Answer (score 1):

The HTML <base href=""/> doesn't work when your <a href=""> start with a /.

Answer (score 0):

it would be a better idea to write a jsp custom tag that you will use instead of the a tag, which will append that path to the begining of your paths.

some think like this:

```
<custom:a href="/some/path" text="blah"/>
```

you may need to add some other attributes like onclick etc as well.